# How to get current Build_user in parameterized jenkins project

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to get current Build user name into Active choice reactive parameter groovy script.

I have tried below code but its not working.

[image: my project is parameterized.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
try {
    def user = hudson.model.User.current().getId()
    return [user]
} catch (e)
{
    return [e.toString()]
}
```

It is always better to use try and catch the exception in the groovy scripts, so as to figure out why it is not working.